# Non-OAuth2 JWT validation with Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, swagger, actions-on-google, google-cloud-endpoints

## My use-case

I have an API deployed on Google Cloud Platform, with Google Cloud Endpoints as the API Manager. For those who are familiar with Endpoints, I'm using the [ESP](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp) on [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/). My API serves as a webhook for an action deployed on Actions On Google. On the API side, I need to verify that the request is actually coming from Actions On Google.

As stated in [the doc](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/verify-requests), the request coming from Actions On Google contains a token (JWT format) in the Authorization header

```
authorization: "<JWT token>"
```

So I need to verify this token with Cloud Endpoints.

## The problem

Cloud Endpoints uses OpenAPI 2.0 (aka Swagger) and the [specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-scheme-object) mentions only the following security schemes: "basic", "apiKey" or "oauth2". It seems that what Actions On Google uses is not based on one of them.

## What I tried

I tried to consider the JWT as an OAuth2 token using the following OpenAPI definition:

```
securityDefinitions:
  ActionsOnGoogle:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    type: "oauth2"
    flow: "implicit"
    x-google-issuer: "https://accounts.google.com"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"
    audiences: "{{ my-gcp-project-id }}"
```

It did not work because Cloud Endpoints ESP checks that the value of the Authorization header starts with "Bearer", otherwise it rejects the request ([code](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/blob/18a0bd3792fc9981c6ed856af6fe883a201453d0/src/api_manager/check_auth.cc#L185))

My second option was to consider the JWT in the Authorization header as an API key. But Cloud Endpoints supports only API keys managed by GCP.

## My question

Is it possible to validate requests coming from Actions On Google with Google Cloud Endpoints?

Comment: I mean, it's definitely possible. I just don't know if it's feasible to pass along the JWT from the AoG header. Maybe you would want to use a bespoke JWT generation within your webhook to verify.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your answer. I'm happy to hear that it's possible. How can I do it? In my OpenAPI definition, do I need to consider the JWT as an "apiKey" or as a "oauth2" token? (in the latter, Endpoints rejects the request with a 401 because the Authorization header does not contain the "Bearer" HTTP authentication type)

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you need to create a custom JWT instead of using the one you're given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, currently ESP doesn't support extracting JWT from this format:

```
authorization: "<JWT token>"
```

Comment: Thanks Wayne, so I just opened a [feature request](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/issues/652).