# How To Pass a Self Signed JWT through Swagger Cloud Endpoints

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-cloud-endpoints

Okay so I seen this QA here

[Non-OAuth2 JWT validation with Google Cloud Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57145885/non-oauth2-jwt-validation-with-google-cloud-endpoints)

This does not quite answer my question. Currently, I have a Node service that generates a Bearer token and passes it to the client. The client then passes the token back on subsequent requests.

The token is created through our auth token service. It is the passed to the client. This works. However when the token is passed back from the client through the API gateway and to the backend service it never makes it to the service.

Here is an example of the bearer token that is passed in

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NR5cCI6IkpkkSXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiWHZYSlZuZDdRZnhMMXZwZ0dTcWwiLCJyb2xlIjoidXNlciIsImlhdCI6MTU4ODczOTg3NywiZXhwIjoxNTg4NzksxjgzMDc3fQ.LJ3YQJMrVX4go-NZ_nfEdT7lrsmFD6kv9WAnDXB3w2ZXDmXn7eJJ5posUxOp5jfu32jpMCNdFywquQ
```

The token goes through the API gateway created through Cloud endpoints (Take it easy on me, Im  new to Google Cloud Endpoints.). So what am I missing and how would I pass the token in?

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title:  API Gateway
  description: Description
  version: 1.0.0
host: {host}
schemes:
  - https
paths:
  /auth/token/decode:
    get:
      summary: Auth Endpoint - Decode Token
      operationId: auth_endpoint_decode
      x-google-backend:
        address: {backend-host}
        protocol: h2
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Token Decoded"
        400:
          description: "Page Error"
  /auth/token/create:
    post:
      summary: Auth Endpoint - Create Token
      operationId: auth_endpoint_create
      parameters:
        - description: "Message to echo"
          in: body
          name: content
          required: true
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              username:
                type: string
              password:
                type: string
      x-google-backend:
        address: {backend-host-2}
        protocol: h2
      responses:
       200:
         description: "Encoded Token"
       400:
         description: "Page Error"
```

So what Im trying to achieve is for the client to be able to pass back the token that was created and for that token to make it into my Node service so that it can be decoded.

Any help is greatly appreciated.. Thank You..

**Update:**

I found that there is a token being passed into my backend service. It just isn't the same as the token that I passed in. So the token I am passing in from the frontend is:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUz21Ni5sIn65cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiWHZYSlZuZDdRZnhMMXZwZ0dTcWwiLCJyb2xlIjoddXN6ciIsImlhdCI6MTU4ODc3NTgyMSwiZXhwIjoxNTg4ODE5MDIxLCJpc3MiOiJhdXRoLXNlc4ZpY2UtbWx5Y3RkNnJlYS11Yy5hLnJ1bi5hcHAifQ.oBI7MaK08Tbg9PQ5vRahdZAS_nhKOWqu4EG5onyNA587KBf2A50eFLRFfkB3AY6t5RXBIbOvUQCXS6UQup1RPg
```

And the token passed into my backend is a much longer token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI14iIsImtpZCI6Ijc0YmQ4NmZjNjFlNGM2Y2L0NTAxMjZmZjRlMzhiMDY5YjhmOGYzNWMiLCJ0eX5iOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJodFRwczovL2F1dGgtc2VydmljZS1xYmZmNHd0YWNxLXVjLmEucnVuLmFwcC9hdXRoL3Rva2VuL2RlY29kZSIsImF6cCI6IjEwNjAwNzMxMjY3MTM0MTM3MzA3MCIsImVtYWlsIjoiMTExOGA4MjE1NjQ4LWNvbXB1dGVAZGV2ZWxvcGVyLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJ7bWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiZXhwIjoxNTg4Nzc5MTgyLCJpYXQiOjE1ODg7NzU1ODIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYWNjb3VudHMuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IjEwNjAwNzMxMjY3MTM0MTM3MzA3MCJ9.qLq4aAJ_UxCoHM00fVJpkvTEPkWZ1VTVelvlGktZ6ldDe9LPsHiE1KmyTxjm7HpKouesY8FmL-lopzArroHJSXfFff-VUujTQ6WI-nrHuRMRUzV7a6PwLCCwoDks6Exp04GG9EjweMcb1ZgQQrCTYk1K1SOCD9sZ2VqROEvV0_YNblFsUJS9b9INeacnhrcYDhi6inlSbsVNKpwqBOZJYE5_W9wLAlIK08RUPOmcLaqBD7pvzSYCZps4K75bOev__xT07yizFppAxlVvqB3PTSTFTCeyCnuUFtJ3kmfNf94Uu51jTpTExPKrumdJ18SLnPoopHJG-GCzSJSmccSOTA
```

Comment: I understood this: when you add  your token in the header of your request, and you request Cloud Endpoint, the forwarded request to your x-google-backend doesn't contain the authorization token, right?

Comment: Actually, I just logged it and I found that it does contain a token but it is different than the one I am passing back? Weird. Is Google adding its own token into the header? So I am gonna post an update in my initial post showing the 2 tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the original `authorization` header, you have to deactivate the endpoint auth. Documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#jwt_audience_disable_auth)

In your path, do this:

```
paths:
  /auth/token/decode:
    get:
      summary: Auth Endpoint - Decode Token
      operationId: auth_endpoint_decode
      x-google-backend:
        address: {backend-host}
        protocol: h2
        disable_auth: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Token Decoded"
        400:
          description: "Page Error"
```

Comment: Such an easy fix but yet I didn't catch it. Thank you guillaume blaquiere